# why read tsconfig.json using readConfigFile instead of directly requiring the path of tsconfig.json?

Tags: create-react-app, tsconfig

Upon investigating [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)'s configuration, I found something interesting.

```
// config/modules.js

...
  if (hasTsConfig) {
    const ts = require(resolve.sync("typescript", {
      basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
    }));

    config = ts.readConfigFile(paths.appTsConfig, ts.sys.readFile).config;
    
    // Otherwise we'll check if there is jsconfig.json
    // for non TS projects.
  } else if (hasJsConfig) {
    config = require(paths.appJsConfig);
  }
...
```

Unlike reading jsconfig.json file using direct `require(paths.appJsConfig)`, why is here using `resolve.sync` and `ts.readConfigFile` to read the tsconfig.json?

```
...
  if (hasTsConfig) {
    config = require(paths.appTsConfig)
    
    // Otherwise we'll check if there is jsconfig.json
    // for non TS projects.
  } else if (hasJsConfig) {
    config = require(paths.appJsConfig);
  }
...
```

If I change the code like just above, the result is same. (at least the console output is same.)

There must be a reason why create-react-app using such a complicated way to read the typescript config file.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The ts config reader is a bit smarter than simply reading and parsing a json file. There's two differences I can think of right now:

- in tsconfig files, you can use comments. `JSON.parse` will throw an exception because `/` is not an allowed character at an arbitrary position
- ts config files can [extend](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#extends) each other. Simply parsing a JSON file will ignore the extension and you'll receive a config object that doesn't represent what typescript actually uses.